# how to specify chrome arguments to java 8 + selenium

Tags: java, selenium, opengl

I am trying to run selenium 3.0 using java 8 on ubuntu 14 with chrome web gl support. I have the following command

```
  java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.args="--use-gl=osmesa" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin=/usr/bin/google-chrome  -log /var/log/selenium/selenium.log > /var/log/selenium/output.log 2> /var/log/selenium/error.log & echo $! > /tmp/selenium.pid
```

For some reason, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -Dwebdriver.chrome.args=--use-gl=osmesa
```

Does anyone know how to fix? I need to use chrome driver with osmesa support.

Answer (score 0):

Put `-jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar` as last argument (right before `> /var/log/selenium/output.log`)